# Angular with lazy loading and child routes setup

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to set up Angular (8) with lazy loading, but I just can't figure out how to make it work.

I have 3 modules, each others having different sub-routes :

- module1 (inside of my app)

  - /home
  - /home/path1
  - /home/path2
- module2 (presentation of the app, public)

  - index
  - presentation
  - features...
- module3 (everything related to access)

  - login
  - register

Anyone would have a working example on how to make this function properly ?

Thanks

EDIT = here's the routing code of my main module :

```
[{
  path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] },
      { path: 'upgrade', component: StripeFormComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService] }
  ]
}];
```

I tried to add lazy loading in the app-routing.module.ts. I reloaded my app, and looked like there was a bit less code, and my module looked like it was loaded lazily however when I tried to access the page, I got a blank page with no explanation. So I'm lost.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you add your code?

Comment: I just added a little more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is  you can decide on some common path names for components within each module ( like how you have 'home' for module 1). Then

```
  `const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./core/core.module').then(m => m.CoreModule) }
   { path: 'module2', loadChildren: () => import('<path to module>').then(m => m.module2) }
   { path: 'module3', loadChildren: () => import('<path to module>').then(m => m.module3) }
 ];`
```

Then within each module, you can define paths for each component likewise

```
`const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'asset/:id', component: AssetComponent },
  { path: 'sub/:id', component: SubCategoryComponent },
];`
```

This way, only the module which contains the component which matches with the path will be loaded.

Comment: Yeah it worked. I was missing this part : { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: just double-check this post: https://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes
because you will have some issues with that configuration

Answer (score 0):

To set route in lazy loading in Angular 8 you have to define a module for the component you want to go, in which you have to define a routing.module:

```
 @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        DetailComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        DetailRoutingModule,
        ChartsModule,
        CommonModule
      ]
    })

export class DetailModule { }
```

While YorComponentDetailRoutingModule is

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: DetailComponent,

}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})


export class DetailRoutingModule { }

In app.routing module you can write:

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: PagesComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent
    },{
      path: 'home/detail',
      loadChildren: () => import('./detail/detail.module')
      .then(m => m.DetailModule),
    } ...
```